# How to change the default TTY after boot?

Tags: linux, console, startup, tty, x-server

Normally when system starts you have all output printed on the TTY1, and that's ok, but I start X-server via `startx` and achieve this by the following lines in the `~/.profile` file :

```
if [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty4 ]]; then
    exec startx &> ~/.xsession-errors
fi
```

So, as you can see I use TTY4 to start X-server, and I want to switch to that console automatically after the boot is done. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the answer. It's simple, you just have to add `chvt 4` to `/etc/rc.local` file, and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

```
# /etc/inittab
4:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f username tty4 < /dev/tty4 > /dev/tty4 2>&1
```

Normally you would have here a getty line, see `man getty`,

```
   agetty opens a tty port, prompts for a login name and invokes the
   /bin/login command.
```

and  `man login`

```
   The login program is used to establish a new session with the system.
```

but this line calls directly login and opens a shell defined in the [Gecos field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) on tty4.

See also `man 5 inittab`.

See also my prevous answer [How to resolve Xserver failure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109542/debian-how-to-resolve-xserver-failure).

Comment: Could you tell me what the line does?

Comment: On Virtual Terminal #4...  When in runlevel 2, 3, 4 or 5...  If the program running here (/bin/login) terminates, restart it (every time it terminates)...  Run the program /bin/login on Virtual Terminal #4, stdin is VT #4, stdout is VT #4, stderr is hooked to stdout.  (not sure about -f username... try man login)